# Ruby On Rails - Resque - Stop Workers / Pid-Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, background-process, resque, pid

I have used this command to start a resque schedule on Ubuntu but how do I do if I want to stop the workers and schedules?

```
PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes QUEUE="*" rake resque:scheduler >>  worker2.log &
PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes QUEUE="*" rake resque:work >>  worker2.log &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run both of those commands then presumably only the last worker will write it's process id to the file. What you probably want to do is not reinvent the wheel and use something like [god](http://godrb.com/) or [foreman](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/) to manage the resque process starting/stopping/etc.

Here's an example god config I've used before: [gist](https://gist.github.com/2793738)

Foreman takes a different approach (and doesn't have monitoring like god does) of using the job management of your OS -- eg. you can have it generate upstart scripts on Ubuntu and then you could run `resque_scheduler [start|restart|stop]` like any other kind of daemon.